# Why changes the orientation of the 3D image when using isosurface vs plot3 and ind2sub?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a indexed 3D image A, that I can visualize with isosurface. 
If I create another version of the same image using ind2sub, when I plot it with plot3, one of the axes is flipped.

Here is an example:

```
    isosurface(A)
    [x, y, z] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A==1));
    plot3(x, y, z,'b.');
```

And here and example image:
[image: image_flipped]

Is this a normal behavior or am I missing anything in the process?

If I go back in the process I reach the same point:

```
    Y = zeros(size(A));
    Y(sub2ind(size(A), x, y, z))=1;
```

Obviously, isequal(A,Y) gives 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) returns rows then columns as the first two outputs, not x,y.

```
[y, x, z] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A==1));
```